# Apex Trigger (before insert): Update the Company Name, During the Creation of a New Lead Record, with the Value in a Custom Lookup Field

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

Using an Apex Trigger, I am attempting to update the Company field, during the creation of a new lead, with the value which the user selected from a custom lookup field on the same object. So, the user clicks new on the lead tab to create a new lead. enters the first name, last name and other details. Instead of typing in the company name, the user then searches for the company name in the lookup field, compName__c, and selects it from the list. What I would like to accomplish is when the the user clicks save, the value in the compName field is copied to the Company field on the new record, then the new record is created.

Here is what I have done thus far;...

```
   trigger UpdateLeadCompany on Lead (before insert) {

Set<Id> AN = New Set<Id>();

For (Lead LeadComp : Trigger.New) 
{
IF(LeadComp.compName__c != null) 
{
AN.add(LeadComp.compName__c);
 }
}

Map<Id, Agency__c> y = [SELECT Name, compName__c FROM compName__c WHERE Id IN :AN];
For(Lead CompNameUpdate : Trigger.New)
{
Company a = y get(CompNameUpdate.compName__c);
IF(a != null)
{
CompNameUpdate = a.compName__c; 
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Updated

Then your code should be like -

```
trigger UpdateLeadCompany on Lead (before insert) {

   Set<Id> AN = New Set<Id>();

   for(Lead leadObj : Trigger.New) {

     IF(leadObj.compName__c != null) {
       AN.add(leadObj.compName__c);
     }

   }

   Map<Id, compName__c> y = [SELECT Name, compName__c FROM compName__c WHERE Id IN :AN];

   For(Lead leadObj : Trigger.New) {

       compName__c a = y.get(leadObj.compName__c);

       IF(a != null) {
         leadObj.Company = a.Name; 
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mukesh, There is the standard field, i.e. Company and a custom lookup field named compName__c. The standard field on the Lead object can't be converted/changed. It seems based on the Company field type i.e. Standard and required, and the order of execution, the Apex trigger may not be work in this case.  Thoughts?

Comment: @user77211 there would not be any issue of order of execution and standard field. You can override the value of field but don't set to blank otherwise you will get the required field error.

Comment: Mukesh, does your statement mean the user must enter text in the company field, then the trigger will rewrite the text in the field with the text selected in the lookup field?

Comment: Yes, but if you don't want to fill any value then you need to create custom VF page for Lead create/update form then you can auto populate the Company field via custom logic i.e. via Javascript on custom VF page.

Comment: I can have the user creating the lead enter a value in the Company field then the code will replace it with the value in the custom lookup field. This should remove the need for a VF page. What would the test class for the above code look like?

Comment: @user77211 you need to just insert a lead record between Test.startTest(); and Test.stopTest();
Then you can assert the results.